# How to pass a datastore from one user object to another

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, datastore

Can someone share how to pass a datastore initiated as an instance variable on the window and create it from a datawindow on a user object and pass it to another user object.

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

- To pass a `datastore` from a `userobject` to another you can use directly the `datastore` type: a procedure or function can have a `datastore` argument or return the `datastore` type.
- if you need to establish a link between two `datawindow`s or a `datawindow` and a `datastore` you can use the `ShareData()` method: any modification on one of the objects (`InsertRow()`, `SetFilter()`, `Update()`, ...) is reflected to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that datastore variables, arguments, etc... are just *pointers* to instantiated datastores. So, something like this:

### UserObject1

**Instance Variable:** 
datastore ids_One
userobject2 inv_Two
**Function of_CreateDS ()**

```
ids_One = CREATE datastore

inv_Two = CREATE userobject2
inv_Two.of_ShareDS (ids_One)
```

### UserObject2

**Instance Variable:** 
datastore ids_Two
**Function of_ShareDS (datastore ads_Share)**

```
ids_Two = ads_Share
```

By the time you get to the end of UserObject1.of_CreateDS(), both UserObject1 and UserObject2 will be pointing at the same instance of one datastore. The tricky part when multiple variables point to the same datastore could be deciding when to DESTROY the instance of the datastore.

Good luck,

Terry.